# Custom citations using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm using the package `natbib`. I want to customize citations of my LaTeX document. Here is my declaration:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat1}
\setcitestyle{authordate,open={(},close={)}}
```

Currently when citing using `\cite` I get citation in this style:  **Patil et al. (2013)** and when I use \citeauthor I get this: **Patil et al.**

I want to customize my commands to have this style:

- **(Patil et al., 2013)** when I use `\cite`.
- **Patil et al. (2013)** when I use `\citeauthor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `natbib` package defines `\cite` as equal to `\citet` (textual citation) and provides `\citep` (parenthetic citation) as a complement. The `\citeauthor` command is meant to give *precisely the authors*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authordate}
\begin{document}

\cite{whole-collection}

\citet{whole-collection}

\citep{whole-collection}

\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you absolutely must change the meaning of the commands, that can be done using `\let`

```
\let\orgiciteauthor\citeauthor % So it is still available
\let\citeauthor\citet
\let\cite\citep
```